# CollectionView error with reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

i have a problem when i try execute the method `reloadData()` in my custom CollectionView.

I would reload data when the parser end to work.

This is the code when i execute reloadData:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SomeStructure.numeroRow = 5
    self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DateCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: dateCellIdentifier)
    self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ContentCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier)
    SomeStructure.numberRow = 200
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse {
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        SomeStructure.numberRow = 190
        self.collectionView ? .reloadData()
    }
}
```

In articular i have problem when the row change size, for example in this code i have try to load layout with 200 rows, and after reload layout with 200 rows.

The error is:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UICollectionViewData.m:417
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 190 - 0}'

**EDIT:**

***cellForItemAtIndexPath:***

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {

                let dateCell : DateCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(dateCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as DateCollectionViewCell
                dateCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                dateCell.dateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
                dateCell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                dateCell.dateLabel.text = ""

                return dateCell
            } else {
                let contentCell : ContentCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(contentCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as ContentCollectionViewCell
                contentCell.contentLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
                contentCell.contentLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                contentCell.contentLabel.text = "200\(indexPath.row)"

                if indexPath.section % 2 != 0 {
                    contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 242/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                } else {
                    contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                }
                println("return content cell")
                return contentCell
            }
        } else {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                let dateCell : DateCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(dateCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as DateCollectionViewCell
                dateCell.dateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
                dateCell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                dateCell.dateLabel.text = String("SeriesKey\nSeriesKey2")
                dateCell.dateLabel.numberOfLines = 2
                dateCell.dateLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
                if indexPath.section % 2 != 0 {
                    dateCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 242/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                } else {
                    dateCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                }

                return dateCell
            } else {
                let contentCell : ContentCollectionViewCell = collectionView .dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(contentCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as ContentCollectionViewCell
                contentCell.contentLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)
                contentCell.contentLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                contentCell.contentLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)/\(indexPath.section)"
                if indexPath.section % 2 != 0 {
                    contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 242/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                } else {
                    contentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                }

                return contentCell
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

```
Method layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: 

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var attributes : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for section in self.itemAttributes {
        attributes.addObjectsFromArray(
            section.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(
                NSPredicate(block: { (evaluatedObject, bindings) -> Bool in
                    return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, evaluatedObject.frame)
                })
            )
        )
    }
    return attributes
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the function cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: What are your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `numberOfCellsInSection` methods?

Comment: And please post your source for `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`

Comment: OK i have edit thanks

Comment: I have try this:

        parser.parse {
            SomeStructure.numeroRow = 190
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            var layout = CustomCollectionViewLayout()
        
            self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }

but not work